# Can't Transform Certain Faces

Tags: transforms, selection-tools

I am unable to move, rotate, or scale certain faces of my model. Many other faces of the model can be transformed, and the untransformable parts of the mesh are still able to be selected in Face and Edge select mode, but not Vertex, and this is true for all the Editor Types I've tested with mesh transformation options. They're also rendered correctly in all Viewport modes I've tried. The only objects in the scene are the mesh and an Armature with two bones but no poses or vertex weightings. Unlike the edges/faces that can be transformed, the untransformable parts aren't deselected when clicking parts of the Viewport with no mesh, unlike the working geometry. The untransformable faces still export correctly as far as I can tell. I am able to use editor tools like Loop Cut on the glitched geometry, but doing so doesn't restore use of transform tools. The immutible geometry doesn't share vertices with the transformable geometry, although it is part of the same object, but that is also true of other fully functional parts. The immutible geometry doesn't seem to contribute to the bounding box of any selection I make. I've already tried separating and rejoining the broken geometry, and closing and reopening Blender.

If this glitch sounds familar to you, I am able to provide more details upon request.

Comment: Can you share the file (or a reduced version of it)? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Agree with @taiyo, we have to see whether we can reproduce this. If it turns out to be a bug, it needs reporting. If we can find another reason, it doesn't.

Comment: How do I share a file? I'm new to Stack Exchange.

Comment: @TT87 upload your blend file here https://blend-exchange.com/ and then add the link as an image in your question (you can edit your post).

Comment: @taiyo I've been waiting for over an hour after selecting my file on Blend Exchange, and the orange progress bar hasn't even started to fill. Is there something else I could do?

Comment: Dunno whats wrong, but then add a link to some public download.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Alright, I found one way to fix the issue. I highlighted the affected area, and hit Delete > Only Faces, then recreated the deleted faces by selecting the edge groups that went around each face, one face at a time, and using "New Face from Edges". Doing this would've really sucked if I wasn't working in a low-poly style and had more than about 20 quads to do this to, so I'd like to hear any other solutions. Maybe there's at least a way to recreate all the faces from edges at once without creating a bunch of degenerated geometry.

Comment: It's happening again, and I'd like to find an quicker solution to the issue. I figured out how to get BlendExchange to work, so if anyone wants to take a look at the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Nls2RymY" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Nls2RymY/)